# How can I prevent win10toast from freeze?

Tags: python

I am using win10toast with my TKinter GUI app, but every time I use it, it freezes my app and it becomes unresponsive. Any alternatives/solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the *threaded* parameter?

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

toast = ToastNotifier()

toast.show_toast("This is the Header",
    "This is the body",
    threaded=True)
```